# Keep Secret Keys Out

Tags: python, django, settings

One of the causes of the local_settings.py anti-pattern is that putting SECRET_KEY, AWS
keys, etc.. values into settings files has problem:

- Secrets often should be just that: secret! Keeping them in version control means
  that everyone with repository access has access to them.

My question is how to keep all keys as secret?

Comment: The accepted answer was deleted for plagiarism, but I put @neuronet's contributions (an attempt to correct the matter) into a community wiki below.

Comment: Removing 'with environment variables' from the title changes the question enough from the original Q that it probablyl should not have been done.

Answer (score 7):

The original question was about how to keep secrets in environment variables. This is discussed extensively in the book [Two Scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11). Below is a summary of what they said, followed by a caveat about using this technique.

Starting on page 48 (Section 5.3) of the edition for 1.11:

> Every operating system supported by Django (and Python) provides the
>   easy capability to create environment variables.
>
> Here are the benefits of using environment variables for secret keys:
>
> - Keeping secrets out of settings allows you to store every settings file in version control without hesitation. All of your Python code
>     really should be stored in version control, including your settings.
> - Instead of each developer maintaining their own copy-and-pasted version of local_settings.py.example for development, everyone shares
>     the same version-controlled settings/local.py .
> - System administrators can rapidly deploy the project without having to modify files containing Python code.
> - Most platforms-as-a-service recommend the use of environment variables for configuration and have built-in features for setting and
>     managing them.

On the following page, the book continues:

> Before you begin setting environment variables, you should have the
>   following:
>
> - A way to manage the secret information you are going to store.
> - A good understanding of how bash settings work on servers, or a willingness to have your project hosted by a platform-as-a-service.

They describe how to set the environment variables locally and in production (with Heroku as an example--you will need to check if you are using a different host this is just one possibility):

> **How To Set Environment Variables Locally**
>       export SOME_SECRET_KEY=1c3-cr3am-15-yummy
>
> **How To Set Environment Variables in Production**
>      heroku config:set SOME_SECRET_KEY=1c3-cr3am-15-yummy

Finally, on page 52 they give instructions for how to access the key. For instance you could put the first two lines below in your settings file to replace the raw key string that is put there by default:

> ```
> >>> import os
> >>> os.environ['SOME_SECRET_KEY'] 
> '1c3-cr3am-15-yummy'
> ```
>
> This snippet simply gets the value of the SOME_SECRET_KEY environment
>   variable from the operating system and saves it to a Python variable
>   called SOME_SECRET_KEY.
>
> Following this pattern means all code can remain in version control,
>   and all secrets remain safe.

Note this will not work in some cases, for instance if you are using an Apache server. To deal with situations where this pattern will not work, you should see Section 5.4 of their book ('When You Can't Use Environment Variables'). In that case, they recommend use a secret file.

As of late 2017, this technique of storing secrets in your environment variables is the recommended best practice in Two Scoops and in the Twelve Factor App design pattern. It is also recommended at the Django docs. However, there are some security risks: if some developer, or some code, has access to your system, they will have access to your environment variables and may inadvertently (or advertently) make them public. This point was made by Michael Reinsch here:
http://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful/

Comment: On the security question: if someone has access to my system, then I am in trouble no matter what I do. Using environment vars seems to be en vogue, is recommended as a viable option at the Django docs, is recommended by the Two Scoops book. It just feels more pythonic. E.g., compared to storing a secret file that is kept out of version control (so then everyone has a different local file: simple is better than complex). Discussion from a few years ago on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461484/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-as-environment-variables-rather-than-as-plain-t

Comment: @neuronet would you mind taking this answer over then and make it coherent instead of disjointed? Thanks for spotting the plagiarism too. If you see any more of that let me know.

Comment: I can give it a shot in the next couple of days. I am far from an expert on this, I've just been reading Two Scoops book, and dealing with environment variables in django lately, and stumbled onto this cut/paste from the book by accident.

Answer (score 6):

Store your `local_settings.py` data in a file encrypted with GPG - preferably as strictly `key=value` lines which you parse and assign to a dict (the other attractive approach would be to have it as executable python, but executable code in config files makes me shiver).

There's a python gpg module so that's not a problem. Get your keys from your keyring, and use the GPG keyring management tools so you don't have to keep typing in your keychain password. Make sure you are reading the data straight from the encrypted file, and not just creating a decrypted temporary file which you read in. That's a recipe for fail.

That's just an outline, you'll have to build it yourself.

This way the secret data remains solely in the process memory space, and not in a file or in environment variables.

Comment: also in other languages encrypted key, value files are a common good practice. Only the dependency to the GPG keyring and that they are configured correctly is something that I would try to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

I doing my Django projects using Windows 7 and Powershell, so for me it was slightly different to set the environment variable.  Once it was set though, I just did the following in my `settings.py` file:

```
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SOME_SECRET_KEY"]
```

To set a environment variable in Windows using PowerShell follow the instructions in the link below:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, `local_settings.py` should not be checked in for production/deployed server. You can keep backup copy somewhere else, but not in source control.

`local_settings.py` can be checked in with development configuration just for convenience, so that each developer need to change it.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Its a better solution than using environment variables, and one of the simpler. I don't know why our answers are getting voted down with no explanation. Just add local_settings.py to your .gitignore and job done. Can you tell git to keep things in the local repo and not push upstream? That would be better. OP doesn't specify their VC system...

Comment: local_settings.py is simpler if possible, but it doesn't work in all situations.  For example, afaict, when deploying to Heroku, you can only use what's checked into git and environment variables, so if you don't want to check the secret_key into git, you have to use an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a getcreds() function which gets the secret key from a file. I keep the file in a place accessible to www-data so wherever I need credentials in settings.py I just make the call to getcreds() passing in the filename as an argument. It returns a list of all lines in the file and bingo I have the hidden secrets. Here is the code ...

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
import os


def getcreds(fname, project, credsroot='/var/www/creds', credsdir=None):
    """ return a list of userid and password and perhaps other data """
    if credsdir is None:
        credsdir = os.path.join(credsroot, project)
    creds = list()
    fname = os.path.join(credsdir, fname).replace("\\", "/")
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # remove leading/trailing whitespace and append to list
            creds.append(line.strip())
    assert creds, "The list of credentials is empty"
    return creds
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it that is compatible with deployment on Heroku:

1. Create a gitignored file named `.env` containing:

   `export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY = 'replace-this-with-the-secret-key'`
2. Then edit `settings.py` to remove the actual `SECRET_KEY` and add this instead:

   `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']`
3. Then when you want to run the development server locally, use:

   `source .env`
   `python manage.py runserver`
4. When you finally deploy to Heroku, go to your app Settings tab and add DJANGO_SECRET_KEY to the Config Vars.

Comment: I had to remove the spaces around the "=" for this to work: export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='replace-this-with-the-secret-key'

Comment: I also had to remove the spaces around the "=" for this to work: export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='replace-this-with-the-secret-key'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`keyring`](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) to store secret keys you don't want in your files.

First set the secret key by calling `keyring.set_password`. This only needs to be done once.

```
import keyring

keyring.set_password("my_app", "secret_key", "af8b6067-c72d")
```

Once set, you can access your key with `keyring.get_password`

```
import keyring

secret_key = keyring.get_password("my_app", "secret_key")
# secret_key = "af8b6067-c72d"
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use os.environ.**get**("SOME_SECRET_KEY")

Comment: Should be `os.environ.get("SOME_SECRET_KEY")`