# Using setup.py install, how can I install dist versions of sensitive config files?

Tags: python, setup.py

In order to [keep secrets out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786072/) of my Github repository, I have created for my Python app a dist version of my secrets file, `config/secrets.py-dist`.

I can manually install the secrets file like so:

```
cp -v config/secrets.py{-dist,}
```

Is there a clean or pythonic way to do this as part of the `setup.py install` command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Secret Keys Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786072/keep-secret-keys-out)

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of that question. IMHO at least. That question addresses the issue of avoiding putting secrets in repositories generally. I've already done that. This is more about automating the setup of the secrets file for an end-user on install and is focused on `setup.py`. I think I can edit question to clarify.